# how to install multiple instance of same windows service

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services

I created one windows serives

It gets the name of the service from web config file.

I used the below link for getting value from webconfig.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx

for installing my windows service,i just click the icon and install
again, i change the value in config file and rebulid my application.

again i try to install, it shows error  like the specified service already exist.

How to install multiple instance of same windows service?

Thanks,
Pooja

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to copy your service executable to a separate directory and use InstallUtil.exe to give it a different service name.

It sounds like you missed this section in [the linked article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx)

> From a command prompt, you'll need to use InstallUtil to install both
>   instances of your service. For instructions on how to use InstallUtil,
>   see [Installer Tool (InstallUtil.exe)](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx). Once you're done installing the
>   service instances, you'll have something like the services console
>   above where *Service Instance 1* and *Service Instance 2* are created from
>   the same executable, only installed from different directory locations
>   with a different service name.

Comment: i try to install using command propemt. it shows installutil is not recodized internal or external command

Comment: It's part of the .NET Framework and it's available in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.

Comment: i used vs2010 command prompt and install windows service, it shows the service is already exist. but i change the service name in config file.

Comment: Did you install the service from a different directory than the first instance?  It must be in a different directory.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You should also look at the answer by @NaeemSarfraz below as well as [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279383/installing-multiple-instances-of-the-same-windows-service-on-a-server) for how to use sc instead of InstallUtil.

Answer (score 16):

I needed to do this for a quick demo of a service running with different parameters.

I copied the directory containing the service exe and then used the `sc create` command to setup the second service.

```
sc create "[NewServiceName]" binPath="[PathToCopiedServiceDirectory]"
```

[How to create a windows service using the Sc.exe command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)

Comment: Make sure that you include the actual service EXE file name in the [PathToCopiedServiceDirectory] value for binPath, otherwise the service will point to the directory and you'll get an "Access Denied" error when you try to start the service.

Answer (score 13):

```
sc create MyService binPath= "MyService.exe" DisplayName= "MyService"  
sc description MyService "My description"
```

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Followed marked answer and wasted an hour. it was simple using sc create command

Comment: Make sure to leave a space after equals and value in binPath and DisplayName

Comment: If there's a space in the MyService reference, use quotes, e.g. `sc create "My Service" binPath= "MyService.exe" DisplayName= "MyService" `

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the service name in the file "ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs" in visual studio and recompile. Hope it helps.

Comment: bit modest as answer should be a comment really

Answer (score -5):

Run the asp.net command prompt as administrator and then use the command - 
installutil "c:\abc\xyz.exe".

If your service is already install then you can uninstall first using the command - 
installutil \u "c:\abc\xyz.exe"

Comment: This is not answering the question.