# How to start two services in separate instances

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am starting WCF services from a Windows service. But at the same time I need to start another Windows service from the same windows service in separate instance.

Below is the code which I am using for starting a single WCF service.

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new WCFService() 
        };

        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

I need help to start another service from this service in separate instance, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725082/how-to-install-multiple-instance-of-same-windows-service

Comment: @Mohank, I want to call another service in the same Main method. I do not want to create same service as another instance.
Actually if I run this windows service it should start one WCF service and another windows service(In this folder watch functionality is written)

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in below link
[Multiple Windows Services in One exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816437/multiple-windows-services-in-one-exe)

We need to add one more Windows Service file in the same file and need to add installer for that. It will start two services in the same Single Windows service.