# How to use single windows service at multiple instance on same server

Tags: windows-services

I have windows service and i create different different compilation symbol for that service , for using multiple names , Now i want to install that same service on single machine 3 times .

Comment: How are you currently installing your single instance? Using an MSI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279383/installing-multiple-instances-of-the-same-windows-service-on-a-server

Comment: yes i am using msi installer

Comment: There is any link for video ??

Comment: what video are you referring to?

Comment: i want any video link for how to use same windows service for creating multiple instance on same machine

Comment: No video, check out the other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279383/installing-multiple-instances-of-the-same-windows-service-on-a-server You can either take a copy of the deployed binaries that the MSI will have dumped out into program files (or wherever) and use SC, or take a build from the source and use SC